# Solve the differential inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $\sigma$ be a differentiable function satisfying the differential inequality $$|\sigma'(x)|\le K\sigma(x)$$ for $\infty \le x \le \infty$ where K is a constant.Then, $$\sigma(x) \le \sigma(a)e^{K|x-a|}$$, for any $-\infty \le a \le \infty$

I'm having trouble with the modulus sign and also do I've to deal with cases $a<x$ and $x<a$ separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider quotients $\displaystyle\frac{\sigma(x)}{{\rm e}^{K(x-a)}}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\sigma(x)}{{\rm e}^{K(a-x)}}$. Their derivatives are non-positive and non-negative respectively, for all $x$. Given a fixed $a$, for $x>a$ use the monotony of the first quotient function to show the required inequality, for $x<a$ use the monotony of the second one.

Comment: @NeerajBhauryal any problem with my answer?

Comment: yes its perfectly fine!